Pandas DataFrame conditional fullfilling based on the index value
I have the pandas dataframe where I save the information about students sports activity in some summer camp. Every visit the student can choose between the limited options of the sports (i the following examples 3 different disciplines). My dataframe is organized in the next way:

Name
Year or Nr of the visit
Sport activity in the current year
Sport 1
Sport 2
Sport 3
etc... (if necessary)

Some example before update (actually input dataframe) is
Name Nr Activity Football Badminton Swimming
Mike 1  Football  0        0         0
Mike 2  Football  0        0         0
Mike 3  Badminton 0        0         0
Mike 4  Football  0        0         0
Mike 5  Swimming  0        0         0

and after update (my output)
Name Nr Activity Football Badminton Swimming
Mike 1  Football  1        0         0
Mike 2  Football  2        0         0
Mike 3  Badminton 2        1         0
Mike 4  Football  3        1         0
Mike 5  Swimming  3        1         1

After 5 years I know that Mike has 3 years experience in the football, 1 year in badminton and 1 year in swimming. But for me is very important to know that for example after 3 years in camp Mike has exactly 2 years activity in football and 1 year experience in the badminton (and swimming has initial value 0, no experience!).
This is the reason, why I can not just update the significant row with df['Badminton'][df['Nr']==3]=1
I have to update not only 1 row, but also all rows with the index greater > .iloc[3] Because I want to know in the fourth and fifth years that Mike has exactly 1 year of experience in the badminton (became in the year 3)

You can one-hot encode the Activity, then compute a groupby.cumsum, and finally update the original DataFrame in place:
df.update(pd.get_dummies(df['Activity']).groupby(df['Name']).cumsum())

Updated df:
   Name  Nr   Activity  Football  Badminton  Swimming
0  Mike   1   Football         1          0         0
1  Mike   2   Football         2          0         0
2  Mike   3  Badminton         2          1         0
3  Mike   4   Football         3          1         0
4  Mike   5   Swimming         3          1         1

If the Football/Badminton/Swimming columns are not pre-existing, you can join:
out = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['Activity']).groupby(df['Name']).cumsum())

NB. If you have Several activities in a given year (e.g. 'Football|Badminton') you could replace pd.get_dummies(df['Activity']) by df['Activity'].str.get_dummies().
